# "unknown drawble resource" error

Tags: android

1) I'm seeing **"unknown drawble resource"** error when I use:`"android:src="@drawble/party""`
The complete code is shown below. What's the issue as my **"party.jpg"** file is under res/drawble folder?

2) I also see an error with `"android:layout_alignRight="8dp"`" What's the issue here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="park.hannah.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawble/party" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="From. Hyunji"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Happy Tuesday!!"
        android:layout_alignRight="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show screenshot of your root files along with drawable folder.

Comment: I didn't create a root file for this code. Should I have one or is that automatically created and I can simply pull off from a folder?

Comment: take screenshot of left side of screen in android studio where all of your folders are shown such as manifest, package name, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOU HAVE SYNTAX ERROR**

@drawable/party instead of @drawble/party

use this

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/party" />
```

> I also see an error with "android:layout_alignRight="8dp"" What's the
>   issue here?

you must align a view depend on another view by ID

### suggestions

you can also use gravity right instead of android:layout_alignRight for **not complex view layouts**

try to use LinearLayout easy and comfort for **not complex view layouts**

Comment: It still gives me "unknown resource drawble" error. Do I need to pinpoint or call "drawble" folder in the beginning?

Comment: Error:error: '@drawble/party' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
Error:error: '8dp' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_alignRight (attr) reference.
Error:'@drawble/party' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
Error:'8dp' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_alignRight (attr) reference.

Comment: Omg I was blind. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

rename  your drawable from *.jpg to *.png